# Override RAM for Android Emulator w/ Play Store Built-In

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Just wondering whether anyone is able to override the RAM when you select one of the pre-configured device definition.

I seem to be unable to modify it. GIF below:

[image]

I searched around online and unable to find anything mentioning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify the config.ini manually:

```
/Users/<username>/.android/avd/<your_avd>.avd/config.ini
```

Find `hw.ramSize`, and override that.

Comment: Its not work for me apply the change but emulator not changed

Comment: Doesn't work anymore.