# Override RAM ,screen size and more for Android Emulator with Play Store Built-In

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have tried to change config.ini by
Open location on the disk where AVD data is saved

```
hw.ramSize=5536

hw.lcd.density=220
hw.lcd.height=1000
hw.lcd.width=500

vm.heapSize=2256
```

also
In Android Studio click File > Reload All from Disk

When I select View Details nothing changed.

I don't sure is there anything to do with this?

```
hw.device.hash2=MD5:6b5943207fe196d842659d2e43022e20
```

I also double check when I change avd name the config.ini changed as well so I think I am looking on the right file.

links to my research and none of them work for me

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

[Can't change the Ram size in AVD manager android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517553/cant-change-the-ram-size-in-avd-manager-android-studio)

[How can I change the ram amount that the android emulator is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40068344/how-can-i-change-the-ram-amount-that-the-android-emulator-is-using)

[How to change the android emulator RAM size from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322540/how-to-change-the-android-emulator-ram-size-from-the-command-line)

[Override RAM for Android Emulator w/ Play Store Built-In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623233/override-ram-for-android-emulator-w-play-store-built-in)

Comment: Ever found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the to the desired value in the file `hardware-qemu.ini` and `config.ini`, In my case I increased it to 16GB. `hw.ramSize=16000`

You also need to remove the `hardware-qemu.ini.lock` and run the emulator again. The Updated data should be reflected.

[image]